# Write on JSON file on SD card with Arduino

Tags: json, arduino, sd-card

I have an Arduino project where I need to write a JSON file on an SD card.

I'm using the SD library from arduino. If I write my content in a **.txt** file, I got no problems but if I change extension to put **.json** I can't write on the file.

This is the working test code :

```
#include <SD.h>
const int chipSelect = 4;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
 // make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
 // output, even if you don't use it:
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
 // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
 if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
 Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
 // don't do anything more:
 return;
 }
 Serial.println("card initialized.");
}
void loop()
{
 String dataString = "";
 File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);
 if (dataFile) {
   dataFile.println(dataString);
   dataFile.close();
   Serial.println(dataString);
 }
 else {
  Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
 }
}
```

This is the code doesn't work :

```
#include <SD.h>
const int chipSelect = 4;
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(115200);
 Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
 // make sure that the default chip select pin is set to
 // output, even if you don't use it:
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
 // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
 if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
 Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
 // don't do anything more:
 return;
 }
 Serial.println("card initialized.");
}
void loop()
{
 String dataString = "";
 File dataFile = SD.open("datalog.json", FILE_WRITE);
 if (dataFile) {
   dataFile.println(dataString);
   dataFile.close();
   Serial.println(dataString);
 }
 else {
  Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
 }
}
```

I have no idea where the problem come from

Thank you in advance

Thomas

Answer (score 2):

> The SD library ... uses short 8.3 names for files.

[source](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD)

Comment: Can I use another library to do this or is it impossible to create JSON file ?

Comment: The problem is not that you're trying to create a JSON file.

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that the filename you're using doesn't fit the 8.3 limit.

Comment: My question is there is any way to use 8.4 ?

Comment: Not with that library.

Comment: Do you know any library to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [SDFat library](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat-beta). It's in beta and supports long file names